# What is the recommended method to transport machine learning models?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm currently working on a machine learning problem and created a model in *Dev* environment where the data set is low in the order of few hundred thousands. How do I transport the model to *Production*  environment where data set is very large in the order of billions.

Is there any general recommended way to transport machine learning models?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which Development Platform your using. I know that DL4J uses Hadoop Hyper Parameter server. I write my ML progs in C++ and use my own generated data, TensorFlow and others use Data that is compressed and unpacked using Python. For Realtime data I would suggest using one of the Boost librarys as I have found it useful in dealing with large amounts of RT data for example Image Processing with OpenCV. But I imagine there must be an equivalent set of librarys suited to your data. CSV data is easy to process using C++ or Python. Realtime (Boost), Images (OpenCV), csv (Python) or you can just write a program that pipes the data into your program using Bash (Tricky). You could have it buffer the data somehow and then routinely serve the data to your ML program and then retrieve the data and store it in a Mysql Database. Sounds like you need a Data server or a Data management program so the ML algo just works away on its chunk of data. Hope that helps.